# How to extract the following value from a file?

Tags: string-manipulation, data

Consider the following file:

```
<LesHouchesEvents version="3.0">
<header>
<!--
#*********************************************************************
#                                                                    *
#                        MadGraph5_aMC@NLO                           *
#                                                                    *
#                           Going Beyond                             *
#                                                                    *
#                   http://madgraph.hep.uiuc.edu                     *
#                   http://madgraph.phys.ucl.ac.be                   *
#                   http://amcatnlo.cern.ch                          *
#                                                                    *
#                     The MadGraph5_aMC@NLO team                     *
#                                                                    *
#....................................................................*
#                                                                    *
# This file contains all the information necessary to reproduce      *
# the events generated:                                              *
#                                                                    *
# 1. software version                                                *
# 2. proc_card          : code generation info including model       *
# 3. param_card         : model primary parameters in the LH format  *
# 4. run_card           : running parameters (collider and cuts)     *
# 5. pythia_card        : present only if pythia has been run        *
# 6. pgs_card           : present only if pgs has been run           *
# 7. delphes_cards      : present only if delphes has been run       *
#                                                                    *
#                                                                    *
#*********************************************************************
-->
<MGVersion>
3.4.0
</MGVersion>
<MG5ProcCard>
<![CDATA[
#************************************************************
#*                     MadGraph5_aMC@NLO                    *
#*                                                          *
#*                *                       *                 *
#*                  *        * *        *                   *
#*                    * * * * 5 * * * *                     *
#*                  *        * *        *                   *
#*                *                       *                 *
#*                                                          *
#*                                                          *
#*         VERSION 3.4.0                 2022-05-06         *
#*                                                          *
#*    The MadGraph5_aMC@NLO Development Team - Find us at   *
#*    https://server06.fynu.ucl.ac.be/projects/madgraph     *
#*                                                          *
#************************************************************
#*                                                          *
#*               Command File for MadGraph5_aMC@NLO         *
#*                                                          *
#*     run as ./bin/mg5_aMC  filename                       *
#*                                                          *
#************************************************************
set group_subprocesses Auto
set ignore_six_quark_processes False
set low_mem_multicore_nlo_generation False
set complex_mass_scheme False
set include_lepton_initiated_processes False
set gauge unitary
set loop_optimized_output True
set loop_color_flows False
set max_npoint_for_channel 0
set default_unset_couplings 99
set max_t_for_channel 99
set zerowidth_tchannel True
set nlo_mixed_expansion True
import model sm
define p = g u c d s u~ c~ d~ s~
define j = g u c d s u~ c~ d~ s~
define l+ = e+ mu+
define l- = e- mu-
define vl = ve vm vt
define vl~ = ve~ vm~ vt~
import model Neutrinophilic-simple_UFO
import model Neutrinophilic-simple_UFO
import model Neutrinophilic-simple_UFO
import model Neutrinophilic-simple_UFO
import model Neutrinophilic-simple_UFO
import model Neutrinophilic-simple_UFO
import model Neutrinophilic-simple_UFO
generate vm~ p > mu+ phi j
output Neutrinophilic-DIS-3-GeV
]]>
</MG5ProcCard>
<MGProcCard>
#*********************************************************************
#                        MadGraph/MadEvent                           *
#                   http://madgraph.hep.uiuc.edu                     *
#                                                                    *
#                          proc_card.dat                             *
#*********************************************************************
#                                                                    *
#            This Files is generated by MADGRAPH 5                   *
#                                                                    *
# WARNING: This Files is generated for MADEVENT (compatibility issue)*
#          This files is NOT a valid MG4 proc_card.dat               *
#          Running this in MG4 will NEVER reproduce the result of MG5*
#                                                                    *
#*********************************************************************
#*********************************************************************
# Process(es) requested : mg2 input                                  *
#*********************************************************************
# Begin PROCESS # This is TAG. Do not modify this line
vm~ p > mu+ phi j           #Process
# Be carefull the coupling are here in MG5 convention
          
end_coup           # End the couplings input

done               # this tells MG there are no more procs
# End PROCESS  # This is TAG. Do not modify this line
#*********************************************************************
# Model information                                                  *
#*********************************************************************
# Begin MODEL  # This is TAG. Do not modify this line
Neutrinophilic-simple_UFO
# End   MODEL  # This is TAG. Do not modify this line
#*********************************************************************
# Start multiparticle definitions                                    *
#*********************************************************************
# Begin MULTIPARTICLES # This is TAG. Do not modify this line

# End  MULTIPARTICLES # This is TAG. Do not modify this line
</MGProcCard>
<MGRunCard>
<![CDATA[
#*********************************************************************
#                       MadGraph5_aMC@NLO                            *
#                                                                    *
#                     run_card.dat MadEvent                          *
#                                                                    *
#  This file is used to set the parameters of the run.               *
#                                                                    *
#  Some notation/conventions:                                        *
#                                                                    *
#   Lines starting with a '# ' are info or comments                  *
#                                                                    *
#   mind the format:   value    = variable     ! comment             *
#                                                                    *
#   To display more options, you can type the command:               *
#      update to_full                                                *
#*********************************************************************
#                                                                    
#*********************************************************************
# Tag name for the run (one word)                                    *
#*********************************************************************
  tag_1 = run_tag ! name of the run 
#*********************************************************************
# Number of events and rnd seed                                      *
# Warning: Do not generate more than 1M events in a single run       *
#*********************************************************************
  10000 = nevents ! Number of unweighted events requested 
 27 = iseed ! rnd seed (0=assigned automatically=default))
#*********************************************************************
# Collider type and energy                                           *
# lpp: 0=No PDF, 1=proton, -1=antiproton, 2=elastic photon of proton,*
#             +/-3=PDF of electron/positron beam                     *
#             +/-4=PDF of muon/antimuon beam                         *
#*********************************************************************
  0 = lpp1 ! beam 1 type 
  1 = lpp2 ! beam 2 type
  12.0  = ebeam1 ! beam 1 total energy in GeV
  0.938 = ebeam2 ! beam 2 total energy in GeV
#*********************************************************************
# Beam polarization from -100 (left-handed) to 100 (right-handed)    *
#*********************************************************************
  -100.0    = polbeam1 ! beam polarization for beam 1
  0.0   = polbeam2 ! beam polarization for beam 2


#*********************************************************************
# PDF CHOICE: this automatically fixes alpha_s and its evol.         *
# pdlabel: lhapdf=LHAPDF (installation needed) [1412.7420]           *
#          iww=Improved Weizsaecker-Williams Approx.[hep-ph/9310350] *
#          eva=Effective W/Z/A Approx.       [21yy.zzzzz]            *
#          none=No PDF, same as lhapdf with lppx=0                   *
#*********************************************************************
  none  = pdlabel1 ! PDF type for beam #1
  nn23lo1   = pdlabel2 ! PDF type for beam #2
  230000    = lhaid ! if pdlabel=lhapdf, this is the lhapdf number
# To see heavy ion options: type "update ion_pdf"
#*********************************************************************
# Renormalization and factorization scales                           *
#*********************************************************************
  True  = fixed_ren_scale ! if .true. use fixed ren scale
  True  = fixed_fac_scale1 ! if .true. use fixed fac scale for beam 1
  True  = fixed_fac_scale2 ! if .true. use fixed fac scale for beam 2
  91.188    = scale ! fixed ren scale
  91.188    = dsqrt_q2fact1 ! fixed fact scale for pdf1
  91.188    = dsqrt_q2fact2 ! fixed fact scale for pdf2
  -1    = dynamical_scale_choice ! Choose one of the preselected dynamical choices
  1.0   = scalefact ! scale factor for event-by-event scales

  0 = ievo_eva ! scale evolution for EW pdfs (eva):
                         ! 0 for evo by q^2; 1 for evo by pT^2

#*********************************************************************
# Type and output format
#*********************************************************************
  False = gridpack !True = setting up the grid pack
  -1.0  = time_of_flight ! threshold (in mm) below which the invariant livetime is not written (-1 means not written)
  average   = event_norm ! average/sum. Normalization of the weight in the LHEF
# To see MLM/CKKW  merging options: type "update MLM" or "update CKKW"

#*********************************************************************
#
#*********************************************************************
# Phase-Space Optimization strategy (basic options)
#*********************************************************************
  0 = nhel ! using helicities importance sampling or not.
                             ! 0: sum over helicity, 1: importance sampling
  2 = sde_strategy ! default integration strategy (hep-ph/2021.00773)
                             ! 1 is old strategy (using amp square)
                 ! 2 is new strategy (using only the denominator)
# To see advanced option for Phase-Space optimization: type "update psoptim"                 
#*********************************************************************
# Generation bias, check the wiki page below for more information:   *
#  'cp3.irmp.ucl.ac.be/projects/madgraph/wiki/LOEventGenerationBias' *
#*********************************************************************
  None  = bias_module ! Bias type of bias, [None, ptj_bias, -custom_folder-]
  {}    = bias_parameters ! Specifies the parameters of the module.
#
#*******************************                                                 
# Parton level cuts definition *
#*******************************
  0.0   = dsqrt_shat ! minimal shat for full process
#                                                                    
#
#*********************************************************************
# BW cutoff (M+/-bwcutoff*Gamma) ! Define on/off-shell for "$" and decay  
#*********************************************************************
  15.0  = bwcutoff ! (M+/-bwcutoff*Gamma)
#*********************************************************************
# Standard Cuts                                                      *
#*********************************************************************
# Minimum and maximum pt's (for max, -1 means no cut)                *
#*********************************************************************
  0.0   = ptj ! minimum pt for the jets 
  0.0   = ptl ! minimum pt for the charged leptons 
  -1.0  = ptjmax ! maximum pt for the jets
  -1.0  = ptlmax ! maximum pt for the charged leptons
  {'88288': 0.5}    = pt_min_pdg ! pt cut for other particles (use pdg code). Applied on particle and anti-particle
  {}    = pt_max_pdg ! pt cut for other particles (syntax e.g. {6: 100, 25: 50}) 
#
# For display option for energy cut in the partonic center of mass frame type 'update ecut'
#
#*********************************************************************
# Maximum and minimum absolute rapidity (for max, -1 means no cut)   *
#*********************************************************************
  -1.0  = etaj ! max rap for the jets 
  -1.0  = etal ! max rap for the charged leptons 
  0.0   = etalmin ! main rap for the charged leptons
  {}    = eta_min_pdg ! rap cut for other particles (use pdg code). Applied on particle and anti-particle
  {}    = eta_max_pdg ! rap cut for other particles (syntax e.g. {6: 2.5, 23: 5})
#*********************************************************************
# Minimum and maximum DeltaR distance                                *
#*********************************************************************
  0.0   = drjl ! min distance between jet and lepton 
  -1.0  = drjlmax ! max distance between jet and lepton
#*********************************************************************
# Minimum and maximum invariant mass for pairs                       *
#*********************************************************************
  {}    = mxx_min_pdg ! min invariant mass of a pair of particles X/X~ (e.g. {6:250})
  {'default': False}    = mxx_only_part_antipart ! if True the invariant mass is applied only 
                       ! to pairs of particle/antiparticle and not to pairs of the same pdg codes.  
#*********************************************************************
# Inclusive cuts                                                     *
#*********************************************************************
#*********************************************************************
# maximal pdg code for quark to be considered as a light jet         *
# (otherwise b cuts are applied)                                     *
#*********************************************************************
  4 = maxjetflavor ! Maximum jet pdg code
#*********************************************************************
#
#*********************************************************************
# Store info for systematics studies                                 *
# WARNING: Do not use for interference type of computation           *
#*********************************************************************
  True  = use_syst ! Enable systematics studies
#
  systematics   = systematics_program ! none, systematics [python], SysCalc [depreceted, C++]
  ['--mur=0.5,1,2', '--muf=0.5,1,2', '--pdf=errorset']  = systematics_arguments ! see: https://cp3.irmp.ucl.ac.be/projects/madgraph/wiki/Systematics#Systematicspythonmodule
]]>
</MGRunCard>
<slha>
######################################################################
## PARAM_CARD AUTOMATICALY GENERATED BY MG5                       ####
######################################################################
###################################
## INFORMATION FOR FRBLOCK
###################################
BLOCK FRBLOCK # 
      1 1.000000e+00 # gphi
      2 2.327350e-01 # gpnw
      3 2.327350e-01 # gnumumw
###################################
## INFORMATION FOR MASS
###################################
BLOCK MASS # 
      5 4.700000e+00 # mb
      6 1.720000e+02 # mt
      15 1.777000e+00 # mta
      23 9.118760e+01 # mz
      25 1.250000e+02 # mh
      88188 9.380000e-01 # mp
      88189 9.390000e-01 # mn
      88190 0.000000e+00 # mnumu
      88288 2.000000e-01 # mphi
      1 0.000000e+00 # d : 0.0
      2 0.000000e+00 # u : 0.0
      3 0.000000e+00 # s : 0.0
      4 0.000000e+00 # c : 0.0
      11 0.000000e+00 # e- : 0.0
      12 0.000000e+00 # ve : 0.0
      13 0.000000e+00 # mu- : 0.0
      14 0.000000e+00 # vm : 0.0
      16 0.000000e+00 # vt : 0.0
      21 0.000000e+00 # g : 0.0
      22 0.000000e+00 # a : 0.0
      24 7.982436e+01 # w+ : cmath.sqrt(mz__exp__2/2. + cmath.sqrt(mz__exp__4/4. - (aew*cmath.pi*mz__exp__2)/(gf*sqrt__2)))
###################################
## INFORMATION FOR SMINPUTS
###################################
BLOCK SMINPUTS # 
      1 1.279000e+02 # aewm1
      2 1.166370e-05 # gf
      3 1.300000e-01 # as (note that parameter not used if you use a pdf set)
###################################
## INFORMATION FOR YUKAWA
###################################
BLOCK YUKAWA # 
      5 4.700000e+00 # ymb
      6 1.720000e+02 # ymt
      15 1.777000e+00 # ymtau
###################################
## INFORMATION FOR DECAY
###################################
DECAY 6 1.508336e+00 # wt
DECAY 23 2.495200e+00 # wz
DECAY 24 2.085000e+00 # ww
DECAY 25 4.070000e-03 # wh
DECAY 88188 0.000000e+00 # wnp
DECAY 88189 0.000000e+00 # wnn
DECAY 1 0.000000e+00 # d : 0.0
DECAY 2 0.000000e+00 # u : 0.0
DECAY 3 0.000000e+00 # s : 0.0
DECAY 4 0.000000e+00 # c : 0.0
DECAY 5 0.000000e+00 # b : 0.0
DECAY 11 0.000000e+00 # e- : 0.0
DECAY 12 0.000000e+00 # ve : 0.0
DECAY 13 0.000000e+00 # mu- : 0.0
DECAY 14 0.000000e+00 # vm : 0.0
DECAY 15 0.000000e+00 # ta- : 0.0
DECAY 16 0.000000e+00 # vt : 0.0
DECAY 21 0.000000e+00 # g : 0.0
DECAY 22 0.000000e+00 # a : 0.0
DECAY 88190 0.000000e+00 # numu : 0.0
DECAY 88288 0.000000e+00 # phi : 0.0
###################################
## INFORMATION FOR QNUMBERS 88188
###################################
BLOCK QNUMBERS 88188 #  np
      1 3 # 3 times electric charge
      2 2 # number of spin states (2s+1)
      3 1 # colour rep (1: singlet, 3: triplet, 8: octet)
      4 1 # particle/antiparticle distinction (0=own anti)
###################################
## INFORMATION FOR QNUMBERS 88189
###################################
BLOCK QNUMBERS 88189 #  nn
      1 0 # 3 times electric charge
      2 2 # number of spin states (2s+1)
      3 1 # colour rep (1: singlet, 3: triplet, 8: octet)
      4 1 # particle/antiparticle distinction (0=own anti)
###################################
## INFORMATION FOR QNUMBERS 88190
###################################
BLOCK QNUMBERS 88190 #  numu
      1 0 # 3 times electric charge
      2 2 # number of spin states (2s+1)
      3 1 # colour rep (1: singlet, 3: triplet, 8: octet)
      4 0 # particle/antiparticle distinction (0=own anti)
###################################
## INFORMATION FOR QNUMBERS 88288
###################################
BLOCK QNUMBERS 88288 #  phi
      1 0 # 3 times electric charge
      2 1 # number of spin states (2s+1)
      3 1 # colour rep (1: singlet, 3: triplet, 8: octet)
      4 0 # particle/antiparticle distinction (0=own anti)
</slha>
<MGPythiaCard>
<![CDATA[
!
! It is possible to run this card manually with:
!    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/name/Downloads/mg5/HEPTools/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH /home/name/Downloads/mg5/HEPTools/MG5aMC_PY8_interface/MG5aMC_PY8_interface tag_1_pythia8.cmd
!
!
! Pythia8 cmd card automatically generated by MadGraph5_aMC@NLO
! For more information on the use of the MG5aMC / Pythia8 interface, visit
!    https://cp3.irmp.ucl.ac.be/projects/madgraph/wiki/LOPY8Merging
!
! ==================
! General parameters 
! ==================
!
Main:numberOfEvents      = -1
!
! -------------------------------------------------------------------
! Specify the HEPMC output of the Pythia8 shower. You can set it to:
!   hepmc       : MG5aMC will automatically place it the run_<i> directory
!   hepmc.gz    : Same as 'hepmc', but also will compress the output file.
!   hepmcremove : MG5aMC will automatically remove the file at the end of the run.
!                 (usefull when running with Delphes)
!   hepmc@<hepmc_path> :
!                 User defined path where the HEPMC file must written. It will
!                 therefore not be placed in the run_<i> directory. The
!                 specified path, if not absolute, will be relative to
!                 the Event/run_<i> directory of the process output.
!   /dev/null : to turn off the HEPMC output.
!   fifo      : to have MG5aMC setup the piping of the PY8 output to 
!               analysis tools such as MadAnalysis5.  
!   fifo@<fifo_path> :
!               Same as 'fifo', but selecting a custom path to create the
!               fifo pipe. (useful to select a mounted drive that supports 
!               fifo). Note that the fifo file extension *must* be '.hepmc.fifo'.
! -------------------------------------------------------------------
!
HEPMCoutput:file         = tag_1_pythia8_events.hepmc
!
! --------------------------------------------------------------------
! Parameters relevant only when performing MLM merging, which can be
! turned on by setting ickkw to '1' in the run_card and chosing a 
! positive value for the parameter xqcut.
! For details, see section 'Jet Matching' on the left-hand menu of 
!    http://home.thep.lu.se/~torbjorn/pythia81html/Welcome.html
! --------------------------------------------------------------------
! If equal to -1.0, MadGraph5_aMC@NLO will set it automatically based 
! on the parameter 'xqcut' of the run_card.dat 
! The following parameter was forced to be commented out by MG5aMC.
! JetMatching:qCut         = -1.0
! Use default kt-MLM to match parton level jets to those produced by the
! shower. But the other Shower-kt scheme is available too with this option.
! The following parameter was forced to be commented out by MG5aMC.
! JetMatching:doShowerKt   = off
! A value of -1 means that it is automatically guessed by MadGraph.
! It is however always safer to explicitly set it.
! The following parameter was forced to be commented out by MG5aMC.
! JetMatching:nJetMax      = -1
!
! --------------------------------------------------------------------
! Parameters relevant only when performing CKKW-L merging, which can
! be turned on by setting the parameter 'ptlund' *or* 'ktdurham' to
! a positive value. 
! For details, see section 'CKKW-L Merging' on the left-hand menu of 
!    http://home.thep.lu.se/~torbjorn/pythia81html/Welcome.html
! --------------------------------------------------------------------
! Central merging scale values you want to be used.
! If equal to -1.0, then MadGraph5_aMC@NLO will set this automatically
! based on the parameter 'ktdurham' of the run_card.dat
! The following parameter was forced to be commented out by MG5aMC.
! Merging:TMS              = -1.0
! This must be set manually, according to Pythia8 directives.
! An example of possible value is 'pp>LEPTONS,NEUTRINOS'
! Alternatively, from Pythia v8.223 onwards, the value 'guess' can be 
! used to instruct Pythia to guess the hard process. The guess would mean 
! that all particles apart from light partons will be considered as a part 
! of the hard process. This guess is prone to errors if the desired hard 
! process is complicated (i.e. contains light partons). The user should
! then be wary of suspicious error messages in the Pythia log file. 
! The following parameter was forced to be commented out by MG5aMC.
! Merging:Process          = <set_by_user>
! A value of -1 means that it is automatically guessed by MadGraph.
! It is however always safer to explicitly set it.
! The following parameter was forced to be commented out by MG5aMC.
! Merging:nJetMax        = -1
!
! For all merging schemes, decide whehter you want the merging scale
! variation computed for only the central weights or all other 
! PDF and scale variation weights as well
SysCalc:fullCutVariation = off
!
! ==========================
! User customized parameters 
! ==========================
!
! By default, Pythia8 generates multi-parton interaction events. This is
! often irrelevant for phenomenology and very slow. You can turn this 
! feature off by uncommenting the line below if so desired.
!partonlevel:mpi = off
!
! Additional technical parameters set by MG5_aMC.
!
! Tell Pythia8 that an LHEF input is used.
Beams:frameType=4
! 1.0 corresponds to HEPMC weight given in [mb]. We choose here the [pb] normalization.
HEPMCoutput:scaling=1.0000000000e+09
! Be more forgiving with momentum mismatches.
Check:epTolErr=1.0000000000e-02
JetMatching:etaJetMax=1.0000000000e+03
! Specify one must read inputs from the MadGraph banner.
JetMatching:setMad=off
! 
!     ====================
!     Subrun definitions
!     ====================
!     
LHEFInputs:nSubruns=1
Main:subrun=0
!
!  Definition of subrun 0
!
Beams:LHEF=unweighted_events.lhe.gz
]]>
</MGPythiaCard>
<MGGenerationInfo>
#  Number of Events        :       10000
#  Integrated weight (pb)  :       9.2277e-06
</MGGenerationInfo>
</header>
<init>
-14 2212 1.200000e+01 9.380000e-01 0 0 247000 247000 -4 1
9.227700e-06 3.975200e-08 9.227700e-06 1
<generator name='MadGraph5_aMC@NLO' version='3.4.0'>please cite 1405.0301 </generator>
</init>
</LesHouchesEvents>
```

It contains the following string:

```
  12.0  = ebeam1 ! beam 1 total energy in GeV
```

Could you please tell me how to scan over the file and extract the single number 12.0?

Comment: Is this materially different from this? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271686/84894

Comment: Please take a look at [`StringCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringCases.html). There are probably several different ways, depending on how the structure of the file changes. One possibility is ``StringCases[text, d : (DigitCharacter | ".") .. ~~ " " .. ~~ "= ebeam1" :> d]``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we import the file as a string, we may use "StringCases" to extract the number. To specify the searched for string "RegularExpression" can be used. E.g. "12.0  = ebeam1 ! beam" can be coded as:

(\d+. \d*) this means 1 or more digits followed by a period followed by zero or more digits. The brackets store the number for later use.

\s+  means one or more space

= ebeam1 ! beam  this is understood literally

Finally we need to convert the string to a number:

```
str = Import["d:/tmp/test.txt"];
ToExpression[
  StringCases[str, 
   RegularExpression["(\\d+\.\\d*)\s+= ebeam1 ! beam"] :> "$1"]][[1]]

(* 12. *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!